# Is it possible to upload a complete directory structure with Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, file-upload, filesystems

Is it possible to upload a complete folder with subdirectories and files (in the subdirectories) in Flex?

I am using a Flex / BlazeDS / Spring application. The question is not how to transfer the data to the server. **The question is: if it is possible to get access to the files and subfolders (recursive) with Flex?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with AIR, then yes.  Look a the [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2) class.  It is a reference to either a file or directory.  You can tell if it is a directory using the isDirectory attribute.  You can use [getDirectoryListing](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#getDirectoryListing%28%29) to get a list of all files and subdirectories in a directory.

As far as I know, you'll then have to upload things one by one to the server, though.

If you are using Flex in a web based app, I do not believe what you're trying to accomplish is possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, not if you are talking about a Flex app running in a web browser. In an AIR application it is probably possible, but not in Flash Player in a browser.

The security sandbox doesn't give that kind of file system access, files are only available when selected by a user, via some user action like clicking a button. And then you only get a reference to the file, so it can be read or uploaded, there is no mechanism to for example get the local path to the file as a string or such, and no way to check for subfolders (unless it's an app for the AIR runtime).